# Insert user type in PHP PDO (for tutis login)

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I'm using the Tutis Login script, [here](http://www.firedartstudios.com/labs/tutis-login).

In the `register()` function, I just want to be able to add one more value to the data that's saved in the database when a new user is created. The script uses a database table `users` with a certain number of columns, and I need one more column, `type`, which I've added to the table in the database.

The problem is I don't know why this code won't work:

```
$database->query('INSERT INTO users(username, password, email, date, type) 
VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :date, :type)', 
array(':username' => $username, 
'password' => $password, 
'email' => $email, 
'date' => $date, 
'type' => 'staff' // this is the line I added, just ensuring the user is 'staff'
));
```

The original code was exactly the same, without the `'type'=> 'staff'` line. When this is run, the rest of the values still get saved correctly in the database when I check, but the `type` column remains empty. I get the following error when I try to register a user:

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in... line database.class.php 71.
```

Following the warning, I've checked, but on line 71 in the `database.class.php` file, this is all there is:

```
/* Execute Query & check for any errors */
if(!$this->statement->execute()){ //this is line 71
    $result = array(
        1 => 'false',
        2 => '<b>[DATABASE] Error - Query:</b> There was an error in sql syntax',
    );
    return $result;
```

I'm really new at PDO, I can check tutorials too (and have), but I haven't been able to figure this out simply. What could be wrong, does anyone have any ideas? What would you look for if you were familiar with PDOs?

Comment: You need to add :type to this part of your query. VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :date) It should match the order of columns provided in the first part of the insert statement.

Comment: @datasage - When using named placeholders, the order doesn't matter.

Comment: @Charles - Yes you are correct. Order matters if you are using indexed placeholders in prepared statements.

Comment: @datasage, I've done that, added :type (check my edited question) but no difference.